# Pandas/Numpy: Calculate current state series based on binary signals

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I have 2 timeseries of binary "signals", let's call them "entry" and "stay".

Entry==1 means add 1 to current state (for some maximum amount of time) and stay==0 means set current state to 0.

```
entry:
0
1
1
0
1
0

stay:
1
1
1
1
0
1
```

My code now calculates a combined current state:

```
state:
0
1
2
2
0
1
```

Currently I use the following code, unfortunately it's (depending on the max-time) quite slow (state/stay/entry are Pandas time series):

```
state=copy.deepcopy(entry)
state[stay==0]=0
#first iteration
state[(entry.shift(1)==1) & (stay==1)]+=1
#2nd iteration to max time
for lag in range(2,max_time+1):
    state[(entry.shift(lag)==1) & (pd.rolling_mean(stay,lag)==1)]+=1
```

Any idea how to vectorize this code for better performance? Many thanks!

Comment: What is ```max_time```? Also, where does ```copy.deepcopy``` come from.

Comment: max_time is the number of periods after entry==1 for which state should be increased by 1 (except there is a stay==0 in the meantime). copy is a python stdlib module and deepcopy is function which copies an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution now, using some NumPy functions:

```
def calc_state_series(entry,stay, max_time=5):
    reduce=(copy.deepcopy(entry)*0).fillna(0) #just for initalization
    reduce[(entry.shift(max_time)==1) & (pd.rolling_mean(stay,max_time)==1)]-=1
    entry=(entry+stay.shift(1)).fillna(0) #reduce state after max_time
    x=entry.values
    x = np.concatenate(([0], x))
    y=stay.values
    y=np.concatenate(([0], y))
    nans = y==0
    x = np.array(x)
    x[nans] = 0
    reset_idx = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=int)
    reset_idx[nans] = np.arange(len(x))[nans]
    reset_idx = np.maximum.accumulate(reset_idx)
    cumsum = np.cumsum(x)
    cumsum = cumsum - cumsum[reset_idx]
    return pd.Series(cumsum[1:], index=entry.index)
```

I manage to avoid the loop and this solution is (depending on max_time) up to 100x faster for me - but there is probably still potential for further optimization.